# Return Map of Maps in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have multiple queries that I'm retrieving using Spring's `jdbcTemplate`. I'm currently using the `queryForList` method. But I want to consolidate all these queries into 1 map with an output like this:

```
{

      customers : {
        firstname : "John",
        lastname: "Doe",
        phone : "1-888-888-8888"
        gender: "M"
     },


     data: {
       key1 : "value1",
       key2 : "value2",
       key3 : "value3"
    },

    etc....

}
```

If I have everything under `customers` as one query:

```
return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(customersql, param);
```

And everything under data as a different query:

```
return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(datasql, param);
```

How can I get my expected output from these two queries using Spring? My understanding is that `queryForMap` returns just 1 row, so that's out of the picture. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is almost certainly a more elegant solution, but at first glance it seems one option is to construct such a map yourself:

```
Map<String, ...> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("customers", jdbcTemplate.queryForList(customersql, param));
map.put("data", jdbcTemplate.queryForList(datasql, param));
return map;
```